# Getting an error while executing goals from maven plugin flexmojos-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, java-8, maven-3, maven-plugin, flexmojos

I get the below error while executing the default lifecycle 'clean install' from my maven project.

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.maven.lifecycle.mapping.LifecyclePhase
```

My code uses the flexmojos-maven-plugin. As per the jira thread https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MNG-5958 this issue has been resolved, but nowhere could I find how.

As per the solution I would have to update Lifecycle.java. Updating Lifecycle.java would mean updating maven-core.jar.

Will I have to go the extent of updating a standard jar which could impact many other files which are using this jar.

I am using maven 3.3.9 and java 8.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Maven guys changed quite a lot internally again with Maven 3.3.9 so currently you will have to use an older Maven version. I also doubt that I will be able to spare the time to address this in the future as Flexmojos has become more and more a beast to maintain. Therefore I am currently working on a completely new maven plugin which I am developing as part of the Apache flex project. For now I would suggest to use Maven 3.3.3 ... should work nicely with that.